# Why is the use of unrelated printf statement causing changes in my program output?

Tags: c, printf

I'm stuck with a program where just having a `printf` statement is causing changes in the output.

I have an array of `n` elements. For the `median` of every `d` consecutive elements, if the `(d+1)th element` is greater or equals to twice of it (the median), I'm incrementing the value of `notifications`. The complete problem statement might be referred [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fraudulent-activity-notifications).

This is my program:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define RANGE 200

float find_median(int *freq, int *ar, int i, int d) {
    int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), RANGE + 1);
    for (int j = 0; j <= RANGE; j++) {
        count[j] = freq[j];
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= RANGE; j++) {
        count[j] += count[j - 1];
    }
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * d);
    float median;
    for (int j = i; j < i + d; j++) {
        int index = count[ar[j]] - 1;
        arr[index] = ar[j];
        count[ar[j]]--;
        if (index == d / 2) {
            if (d % 2 == 0) {
                median = (float)(arr[index] + arr[index - 1]) / 2;
            } else {
                median = arr[index];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    free(count);
    free(arr);
    return median;
}

int main() {
    int n, d;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &d);
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &arr[i]);
    }
    int *freq = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), RANGE + 1);
    int notifications = 0;
    if (d < n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
            freq[arr[i]]++;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - d; i++) {
            float median = find_median(freq, arr, i, d);   /* Count sorts the arr elements in the range i to i+d-1 and returns the median */
            if (arr[i + d] >= 2 * median) {      /* If the (i+d)th element is  greater or equals to twice the median, increments notifications*/
                printf("X");
                notifications++;
            }
            freq[arr[i]]--;
            freq[arr[i + d]]++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", notifications);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, For large inputs like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0wMedxReF5XdVYyYV9mUVR0Vzg), the program outputs `936` as the value of `notifications` whereas when I just exclude the statement `printf("X")` the program outputs `1027` as the value of `notifications`. 
I'm really not able to understand what is causing this behavior in my program, and what I'm missing/overseeing.

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<=RANGE;j++){ count[j]+=count[j-1]; }`... Now what is the contents of `count[j-1]` in the first iteration? You might be interested in learning about [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: One way `printf()` can affect results is by stomping on the data that was a variable in another function where a pointer to the now out of scope data was returned.  It can also alter memory allocation patterns and make a bug more visible

Comment: Another problem is uninitialized variables: the garbage they end up containing depends on previous stack history, which can be drastically affected by `printf` or not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for pointing out the mistake. However, even if the iteration starts with j=1, the problem persists

Comment: Allocating with `d` makes more sense than `RANGE`.  Suggest `int *count = calloc(d, sizeof *count);`  Also reverse operands, drop cast, use sizeof *pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So, what can be done to ensure printf() doesn't overwrite the 'now out of scope variable's data'?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger. Read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Code will not find the _median_ using a single `for()` loop with random ordered input.

Comment: You avoid the problem by not trying to use now out of scope data.  Once it is out of scope, it is no longer usable.  If the `printf()` is scribbling over it, then it is doing you a favour and revealing UB — undefined behaviour.

Comment: We really shouldn't have to go and read the [HackerRank Challenge "fraudulent activity notifications"](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fraudulent-activity-notifications) to understand what your code is doing.  You should include the relevant information in your question.  It is reasonable to reference the challenge for extra information, but your question should be comprehensible without that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the reference to 'undefined behavior'. Also, checked for warnings, and there were none

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the good advice. I've updated/edited my question to make it more comprehensive. However, I've kept back the link to original problem statement, in case anyone wants to dig deeper.

Comment: You should use more the debugger `gdb` and its watchpoints. Use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Read much more about *undefined behaviopr* and work hard to avoid it. With UB the behavior of a program written in C is unpredictable and it is pointless to understand it (without diving into gory implementation details and into machine code)

Comment: @chux Can you please explain how can 'dropping the cast' and 'reversing the operand' be useful?

Comment: @Saksham Dropping the cast is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), keeping the cast is [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions).  By reversing, the variables passed match the intent of `calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program has [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (at *several* occasions). You really should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) (and you are not scared enough).

> I'm really not able to understand what is causing this behavior in my program

With UB, that question is *pointless*. You need to dive into implementation details (e.g. study the generated machine code of your program, and the code of your C compiler and standard library) to understand anything more. You probably don't want to do that (it could take years of work).

Please read as quickly as possible Lattner's blog on [*What Every C Programmer Should Know on Undefined Behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

> what I'm missing/overseeing.

You don't understand well enough UB. Be aware that a programming language is a specification (and code against it), not a software (e.g. your compiler). Program [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) is important.

As I said in comments:

- compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/))
- improve your code to get no warnings; perhaps try also *another* compiler like [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and work to also get no warnings from it (since different compilers give different warnings).
- consider using some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) to keep various variants of your code, and some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool.
- think more about your program and [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(computer_science)) inside it.
- use the debugger (`gdb`), in particular with [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html), to understand the internal state of your process; and have several [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) cases to run  under the debugger and without it.
- use [instrumentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) facilities such as the address sanitizer `-fsanitize=address` of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).
- use [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) methodology
- sometimes consider [static source code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools (e.g. [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)). They require expertise to be used, and/or give many false positives.
- read more about programming (e.g. [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)) and about the C Programming Language. Download and study the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) programming language specification [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (and be very careful about every mention of UB in it). Read carefully the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every standard or external function you are using.  Study also the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc) of your compiler and of other tools. Handle error and failure cases (e.g. [calloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) and [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can fail).

**Debugging is difficult** (e.g. because of the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), of [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), etc...) - but sometimes fun and challenging. You can spend weeks on finding one single bug. And you often cannot understand the behavior of a buggy program without diving into implementation details (studying the machine code generated by the compiler, studying the code of the compiler).

<sup>PS. Your question shows a wrong mindset -which you should improve-, and misunderstanding of UB.</sup>

Comment: The address sanitizer `-fsanitize=address` helped me find several out-of-bounds and use-after-free bugs. Valgrind helped me to find 'uninitialized value' errors and memory leaks.

Comment: The blog you suggested was really really informative. Thanks for it.

Comment: Then upvote or accept my answer. But I was expecting that `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` would also be helpful

Answer (score 6):

Your program has undefined behavior here:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= RANGE; j++) {
    count[j] += count[j - 1];
}
```

You should start the loop at `j = 1`. As coded, you access memory before the beginning of the array `count`, which could cause a crash or produce an unpredictable value.  Changing anything in the running environment can lead to a different behavior.  As a matter of fact, even changing nothing could.

The rest of the code is more difficult to follow at a quick glance, but given the computations on index values, there may be more problems there too.

For starters, you should add some consistency checks:

- verify the return value of `scanf()` to ensure proper conversions.
- verify the values read into `arr`, they must be in the range `0..RANGE`
- verify that `int index = count[ar[j]] - 1;` never produces a negative number.
- same for `count[ar[j]]--;`
- verify that `median = (float)(arr[index] + arr[index - 1]) / 2;` is never evaluated with `index == 0`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this mistake and corrected it. Then also, the same problem continues.

Comment: @Saksham: I do not understand what the code does, but there are many places for more undefined behavior. Answer updated.

Comment: I did the consistency checks but everything seems alright. For the first check, I computed the `sum` of all `scanf()` returns and that matches the value expected. For the second one, the input I'm giving contains all value in range `0..RANGE`. I did the rest of the checks using conditional statements and found no issue. Thanks anyway.